# Negating duplicate words pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am new to regex and have the following pattern that detects duplicate words separated with dashes

```
\b(\w+)-+\1\b
// matches: hey-hey
// not matches: hey-hei
```

What I really need is a negated version of this pattern.
I've tried negative lookahead, but no good.

```
(?!\b(\w+)-+\1\b)
```

Comment: What does it mean to "invert" the pattern? Provide some examples of matches and non-matches for your "inverted" pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\b(\w+)-+(?!\1\b)\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GBZnnQ/2). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `-+` - one or more hyphens
- `(?!\1\b)\w+` - one or more word chars that are not equal to the first capturing group value.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. Very appreciate the lesson